# What minimal, clean, and "event-able" WYSIWYG editor would you suggest (jQuery based ok)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, wysiwyg

Editors that attach to a textarea and make it nice and easy for non-tech savvy users to bold, italic, list, link, etc... while producing good markup, and having a good api (at least a set of events, including an "onKeyPress" type of event).

There are just SO many out there... it's hard to find the "good" ones. I currenly use [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/), it works... but there are a few issues I have with it.

Comment: i like ckeditor. it's a bit heavier i suppose but gets the job done

Comment: "event-able" means that it has events I can hook into, particularly a "onKeyPress" type of event.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want minimal, check out Hallo: http://hallojs.org/

It's really awesome in its simplicity.

Demo: http://hallojs.org/demo/markdown/ (click on the text to activate)
Docs: https://github.com/bergie/hallo/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE - http://www.tinymce.com/ - would be the best one that I could suggest. The community behind it, combined with the projects that rely on it, give it a very solid backing & plenty of references to suit all of your needs.